# Multivariable integrating factor for a non-linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find an integrating factor of the form $u(x,y)$ for the equation
$$(a\cos xy-y\sin xy)~dx+(b\cos xy-x\sin xy)~dy=0$$
using an approach suggested in the comments for this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/139160/170231

I'm wondering if this "greedy" method allows for me to try to find a function $C(x,y)$ such that I can eliminate the appropriate variable when solving for either $F(x)$ or $G(y)$.

Work thus far:
$$\begin{align*}
F(x)(b\cos xy-x\sin xy)\quad&\\
-G(y)(a\cos xy-y\sin xy)&=(-ax\sin xy-\sin xy-xy\cos xy)\\&\quad-(-by\sin xy-\sin xy-xy\cos xy)\\\\
F(x)(b\cos xy-x\sin xy)\quad&\\
-G(y)(a\cos xy-y\sin xy)&=(by-ax)\sin xy\\\\
F(x)&=\frac{(by-ax)\sin xy+G(y)(a\cos xy-y\sin xy)}{b\cos xy-x\sin xy}
\end{align*}$$
and so, based on that post, I would try to look for a constant or function $C$ that, when setting
$$(by-ax)\sin xy+G(y)(a\cos xy-y\sin xy)=C(b\cos xy-x\sin xy)$$
let's me do a proper simplification. Is it possible?

Comment: I think I might have a solution. I tried setting $F(x)=\alpha x^\gamma$ and $G(y)=\beta y^\delta$, and I find that $\alpha=a,~\beta=b,~\gamma=\delta=0$, which gives an integrating factor $u(x,y)=\exp(ax+by)$, which seems to work! If anyone else has any suggestions, please feel free to leave them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way to solve the ODE is :
$$(a+b y')\cos(xy)=(y+x y')\sin(xy)=-\big(cos(xy)\big)'$$
$$a+b y'+\frac{\big(cos(xy)\big)'}{cos(xy)}=0$$
$$a x+by+ln(cos(xy))=C$$

In addition :

With the method that you are trying, you got to:
$$F(x)(b \cos xy-x \sin xy)-G(y)(a \cos xy-y \sin xy)= (by-ax)\sin xy $$
$$(bF-aG)\cos xy-(xF-yG-by+ax)\sin xy= 0$$
$$bF-aG=0$$
$$xF-yG-by+ax=0$$
leading to :
$$F=a$$
$$G=b$$
and the integrating factor is 
$$e^{ax+by}$$
The initial equation becomes :
$$e^{ax+by}(a\cos xy-y\sin xy)~dx+e^{ax+by}(b\cos xy-x\sin xy)~dy=0$$
which is the total differential of $e^{ax+by}\cos(xy)=c$ 
So, the solution on implicit form is :
$$e^{ax+by}\cos(xy)=c$$
or :
$$ax+by+ln(\cos xy)=ln(c)=C$$

Comment: That's a much more efficient way, but the question asks specifically for an integrating factor. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: You're welcome. See the addition to my preceeding answer.

Comment: Integrating factor is $\mu=\sec(xy)$