# Integrating factor of two variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

I am trying to solve the following:
$$
(x + x^2 + y^2) dy - ydx = 0.
$$
with an integrating factor involving both x and y. Indeed, it seems that an integrating factor of only one variable would not be possible. As $f(x,y) = \frac{y}{x+x^2 + y^2}$ is not homogeneous, it seems that route is closed as well.

My tactic thus far has been to try functions of several forms, such as $x^\alpha y^\beta$ and a few polynomials, but have always come up sort, ending up with higher and higher powers of both $x$ and $y$, meaning that I have not been able to find constants such that any variation brings about an exact DEQ.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a general ansatz when dealing with $M$ and $N$ as polynomials of differing degree and with differing constants?
2. Can anyone point me in a direction where I might be able to find something like an integrating factor for this?

I'd be most appreciative of any ideas!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integrating factor having "two variables" in differential equations (first order DE)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4767658/integrating-factor-having-two-variables-in-differential-equations-first-order)

Comment: The OP in the duplicate found this [script](https://math.okstate.edu/people/binegar/2233-S99/2233-l12.pdf) awesome.

Comment: A hint for your second question: you can rewrite the ODE as $\frac{dx}{dy}=y+\frac{x}{y}+\frac{x^2}{y}$, which is a [Riccati equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation).

Comment: Wanted to get back and say that I managed to use the method @KurtG. mentioned combined with a night of decent sleep to find the integrating factor $\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}$, but was beat to it by the answer below! Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrating factor is $\mu=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$

How i find it ?

Let $\mu=f(t)$, $t=x^2+y^2$, $P=-y$, $Q=x+x^2+y^2$.

Then $\mu'_x=f'(t)2x$,  $\mu'_y=f'(t)2y$.

From $(P\mu)'_y=(Q\mu)'_x$ we get differential equation
$$tf'(t)+f(t)=0$$
with solution
$$f=\frac{C}{t}$$

Comment: Nice. How did you find it?

Comment: Brilliant. Your ODE for $f$ is correct. There was no intermediate step $0=t\,f'+f+x\,(t\,f'+f)$ that you left for the reader?

Comment: @KurtG this seems to be the method mentioned above, just done with the specifics of this equation. Certainly writing this up for future use!

Answer (score 0):

All the credit for finding a simple integrating factor goes to ***Aleksas Domarkas***.

I only contribute this answer for two reasons:

- It seems like Aleksas used an intermediate step that is left to solve by more pedestrian readers (like me).
- The ODE really interesting
  and related again to the mother of all differential forms in $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$ that are closed but not exact (see below).

***Notation:***
$$
Q\,dy+P\,dx=0\,,\quad Q(x,y)=x+x^2+y^2\,,\quad P(x,y)=-y\,.
$$
***Ansatz for the integrating factor:***
$$
\mu(x,y)=g(x^2+y^2)\,.
$$
This gives
$$
\mu_x=2\,x\,g'\,,\quad \mu_y=2\,y\,g'\,.
$$
The condition
$$
\partial_y(\mu P)=\partial_x(\mu Q)
$$
gives
$$
\mu_yP+\mu\,P_y=\mu_xQ+\mu\,Q_x\,,
$$
that is:
$$
-2\,y^2g'-g=2\,x\,g'\,(x+x^2+y^2)+g\,(1+2x)\,.
$$
This simplifies to
$$
0=2\,(y^2+x^2)\,g'+2\,x\,g'(x^2+y^2)+2\,g+2\,x\,g\,.
$$
Setting $t=x^2+y^2$ this simplifies further to
$$
0=t\,g'+g+x\,(t\,g'+g)
$$
from which we conclude $0=t\,g'+g$ and thus $g(t)=1/t\,.$
One  integrating factor is therefore
$$
\boxed{\quad\phantom{\Big|}\mu(x,y)=\frac1{x^2+y^2}\,\quad}
$$
(cf. Aleksas).

***Now solving the ODE:***

The [traditional method](https://mathinsight.org/conservative_vector_field_find_potential) of finding
a function $f(x,y)$ whose gradient is $(\mu\,Q,\mu\,P)$ won't work in this
case as I will show in the following.

The ODE $\mu\,Q\,dy+\mu\,P\,dx=0$ now takes the form
$$
\underbrace{\frac{x\,dy-y\,dx}{x^2+y^2}}_{\textstyle\boldsymbol{\omega}}+dy=0\,.
$$
The first term $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ is the mother of all differential forms on $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$ which is [closed but not exact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4605443/showing-why-a-form-is-not-exact/4605719#4605719):  The function
$$
\phi(x,y)=\arccos\Big(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\Big)
$$
(or in polar coordinates $\phi(r,\theta)=-\theta$) solves $d\phi=\boldsymbol{\omega}$ but has a branch cut where it is discontinuous. In other words, it is defined only on, say, the domain $\mathbb R^2\setminus(-\infty,0)\,.$
Obviously
$$
f(x,y)=\phi(x,y)+y
$$
is a function on that same domain that satisfies $df=\boldsymbol{\omega}+dy\,.$

It follows that the solutions of the original ODEs $Q\,dy+P\,dx=0$ and $\mu\,Q\,dy+\mu\,P\,dx=0$ are implicitly given as
the level curves of $f(x,y)=0\,.$

Answer (score -1):

Multiply both sides with a function of $x$ and derive both coefficients of the differential forms with respect to the other variables

$$ d \ \left((a(x) (x^2 + x + y^2) \ dy - a(x) \ y \ dx)\right)  = \left(\ \partial_x \left(a(x)\ (x^2 + x + y^2)\ \right) \ + \ \partial_y\left(\ a(x)\ y \right) \ \right) \ dx \wedge dy$$

If the 2-form is zero,  the 1-form with the factor a(x) is the derivative of a function f

$$d \ f = \partial_x f dx + \partial_y f dy =  - a(x) y dx +a(x) (x^2 + x + y^2) dy)$$

Comment: Your two form is zero if and only if there exists a function $a=a(x)$ such that
$$
a'(x^2+x+\color{red}{y^2})+2ax=0\,.
$$
The $\color{red}{y^2}$ is a bit spoiling isn' it? OP is righfully of the opinion
that the integrating factor must be of the form $a(x,y)\,.$

Comment: This was an answer to the question, if there is a general method. This is the first step. the second,  a function of y, the third a product a(x) b(y) and then a function of $r,f$ in polar coordinates. Transformation to$ (x, y) = r (cos \phi, \sin \phi)$  is trivial in exterior calculus. Formulation without differential  forms is a method creating unsolvable trivial puzzles for dummies.

Comment: I just showed that in OP's case your $a(x)$ does not exist. Even Cartan's magic formulas won't change that situation.

Comment: And besides: once you go to the next step trying to find $a(x,y)$ there will be some work left to do, regardless if you write that as differential form or not.

Comment: $$\left(r^2+r\  \cos (\phi )\right) (\text{dr}  \sin (\phi )+\text{d$\phi $} r  \cos (\phi ))-r \  \sin (\phi ) (\text{dr} \cos (\phi )-\text{d$\phi $} r \sin (\phi ))$$
$$= r^2 (\text{dr} \  \sin (\phi )+\text{d$\phi $} \ ( r \cos (\phi )+1)$$